# Problema com dicts e zip em Python 3

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

estou com problemas na função `dict(zip(x, y))` quando eu passo como parametro as duas listas (`x` e `y`) o `zip` não cria a lista do tamanho original, aleatoriamente cria a lista no tamanho original, mas em sua maioria sempre entre 2 a 5 valores a menos. Isso a supor para `x` que tenha tamanho 100 e `y` também tamanho 100. Ambas `x` e `y` tem o mesmo tamanho. Como resolvo isso? Muito obrigado!

Comment: simplesmente uma de suas listas em algum momento é menor que a outra é a única explicação para que isso aconteça...

Comment: sim, também pensei isso, mas se eu te contar parece inacreditável, pedi para imprimir o tamanho de `x` e de `y` por `len(x)` e `len(y)`. Fiz a operação `zip` em separado e armazenei em uma variavel: `var_exemplo = zip(x, y)`. Imprimi o tamanho da lista: `len(var_exemplo)`. Até aí tudo certo. Mas depois que fiz o dict em separado, gerou um dict com menos índices do que o normal: `novo_dict = dict(var_exemplo)`. O que você sugere? PS: fiz isso muitas e muitas vezes antes de postar aqui, para ter certeza e é isso mesmo.

Comment: só um toque pare de duplicar perguntas, vc fez essa pergunta e horas depois repetiu a mesma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141125/resolver-itens-duplicados-em-dict-no-python-3) tenha calma a comunidade vai te ajudar ....

Answer (score 0):

Sua lista "x" é usad como chave dos dicionários: as chaves dos dicionários são únicas - qualquer valor repetido de x aí vai sobre-escrever o par chave/valor armazenado previamente.

O qe está acontecendo é que você tem alguns valores repetios na sua lista x.

COmo vocẽ não disse mais anda sobre a natureza de seus dados, e saida esperada é só até onde é possível responder.