# Resolver itens duplicados em dict no Python 3

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

estou a ter problemas com meu `dict`. Preciso que ele não exclua os valores de chaves duplicadas. Eu tenho uma tupla estilo `lista_tupla = [(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (2, [5, 6, 7]), (3, [7, 8, 9]), (3, [10, 11, 12]), (4, [13, 14, 15])]` mas quando uso o comando `dict(lista_tuplas)` ele transforma em: `{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7], 3: [10, 11, 12], 4: [13, 14, 15]}`, logo, ele substituiu a chave duplicada que era o 4 pelo último `value` encontrado. Como faço para evitar isso? É obrigatório eu manter ambos, pois embora sejam chaves iguais, os valores entre as chaves são diferentes! Help please \0/ é urgente rsrs

Comment: Uma das formas que pensei, foi em fazer o seguinte: primeiro percorrer a `lista_tupla` e para cada chave igual encontrada, acrescentar um valor para ela, fazendo busca de todos com todos, então ficaria assim: `lista_tupla = [(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (2, [5, 6, 7]), (3, [7, 8, 9]), (3, [10, 11, 12]), (4.0001, [13, 14, 15])]` mas não sei como fazer isso O.o porque na verdade cada chave minha é um float, pois, é o resultado de uma média. Então adicionar um valor muito pequeno não tem problema.

Comment: Mas um dicionário com chaves duplicadas não faz sentido. Por que você acha que precisa de um dicionário?

Comment: Para converter em dicionário, ou você junta os valores das chaves que se repetem, ou não usa dicionário.

Comment: Seria interessante o autor da pergunta esclarecer como proceder em caso de conflito de chaves.

Answer (score 1):

Você não disse o mais importante: o que fazer quando encontrar chaves duplicadas! Um dicionário tem que ter chaves distintas - mas nada impede que cada valor seja ele mesmo outra tupla, ou mesmo outro dicionário, com vários outros dados dentro.

Então, se você quiser que cadachave no dicionário seja uma única lista, com os valores da sua lista concatenados, pode fazer um coigo consizo usando o método `setdefault` dos dicionários: esse método devolve o valor associado com uma chave, caso ele já exista - se não existir, associa o segundo parâmero passado como valor para aquela chave, e devolce o mesmo. Ou seja, `meudict.setdefault("chave", [])` devolve o valor que está em  `meudict["chave"]`, ou coloca uma lista vazia em  `meudict["chave"]`  e devolve essa lista - que podemos então manipular com append ou extend.

Então para concatenar seus valores em listas grandes no caso de chaves repetidas:

```
meu_dict = {}
for chave, valor in lista_tupla:
     meu_dict.set_default(chave, []).extend(valor)
```

Agora, se você não quiser concatenar o conteúdo dos dioncários, mas tornar cada valor do dicionário uma lista cujos items são as outras listas de valores na sua sequêncuia original (dessa forma você preserva a independência dessas sequências), é só trocar a última linha acima por:

```
     meu_dict.set_default(chave, []).append(valor)
```